# Why is this sqlalchemy or_ expression not working with a true clause?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a sqlalchemy declarative model which looks like:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(32), unique=True, nullable=False)

    posts = relationship('Post', cascade='all, delete-orphan', back_populates='owner')


class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(256), nullable=False)
    public = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    owner = relationship('User', back_populates='posts', single_parent=True)
    shared = relationship('User', secondary=shared_post)
```

In my test database, I have a user User1 who has a post Post1. Post1 does not have any shared users associated with it. I tried a query:

```
expr = or_(Post.owner == current_user,  # current_user is ORM User1
           Post.public == True,
           Post.shared.contains(another_user))

posts = session.query(Post).filter(expr).all()
```

However `posts` is an empty list. Here are the individual queries:

```
session.query(Post).filter(Post.owner == current_user).all()  # returns Post1
session.query(Post).filter(Post.public == True).all()  # returns Post1
session.query(Post).filter(Post.shared.contains(another_user)).all()  # empty list as expected
```

Why doesn't the original `or_` work if two out of three individual queries are confirmed working?

Edit #1:

Replacing `Post.shared.contains(another_user)` with `Post.shared.any(User.id == another_user_id)` fixes the `or_` query problem. However now I'd like to know why one works and the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not include your secondary table definition, but I presume it is something like this:

```
shared_post = Table(
    'shared_post', Base.metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer,
           ForeignKey('user.id', ondelete='cascade'), nullable=False),
    Column('post_id', Integer,
           ForeignKey('post.id', ondelete='cascade'), nullable=False)
)
```

A good start to debugging SQLAlchemy queries is to try and print parts of expressions or even full queries:

```
print(expr)  # where expr is the original or_(...)
```

yields

```
:param_1 = post.owner_id OR post.public = 1 OR post.id = shared_post_1.post_id AND :param_2 = shared_post_1.user_id
```

We see that the `.contains()` method has produced an implicit join and an AND of 2 expressions without parentheses: the join predicate

```
post.id = shared_post_1.post_id
```

and the second expression is the actual check for the given user

```
:param_2 = shared_post_1.user_id
```

So your predicates now consist of ORs followed by an AND that will never be satisfied.

The full query is

```
SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.owner_id AS post_owner_id, post.name AS post_name, post.public AS post_public 
FROM post, shared_post AS shared_post_1 
WHERE ? = post.owner_id OR post.public = 1 OR post.id = shared_post_1.post_id AND ? = shared_post_1.user_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer and debugging tips. Would you say that the original `or_` query is working as intended, or should sqlalchemy have inserted parenthesis around `.contains()`?

Comment: @trianta2 intuitively it would feel that it should have parentheses. Reading what [`RelationshipProperty.Comparator.contains`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.RelationshipProperty.Comparator.contains) should do adds to that feeling, but on the other hand in this case because of the join it would fail anyway and as such is the wrong choice. The `any()` you found out yourself produces the correct `EXISTS` expression.

Comment: The linked documentation actually lists this exact case as a caveat of using `contains()` with many-to-many relationships. It will not work with complex OR expressions etc.